# Selenium Python return login page after login success

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I try to scrape content from a website, with login code and otp code after login.
Without using selenium, login and using page is ok. However, when I login by selenium and try to access a page it return login page again

This is my code

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
#options.add_argument("--headless") # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') # Bypass OS security model
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # applicable to windows os only
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Defaul") #Path to your chrome profile
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
#driver=webdriver.Chrome()
site="https:xxxxxx"
# call open browser function
# Github credentials
username = "username"

password = "password"

# head to github login page
driver.get(site)
# find username/email field and send the username itself to the input field
driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(username)
time.sleep(20)
# find password input field and insert password as well
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password)
time.sleep(25)
# click login button
driver.find_element_by_id("btnLogin").click()
otp="xxxxxx"
driver.find_element_by_id("otp").send_keys(otp)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/button[1]").click()
```

I save my session

```
s = requests.Session()
# Set correct user agent
selenium_user_agent = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;")
s.headers.update({"user-agent": selenium_user_agent})

for cookie in driver.get_cookies():
    s.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'], domain=cookie['domain'])
```

Then
driver.get("https:mysite.com/page1")
I return login page again

Thanks for reading and helping me

Comment: can u share url of the page please

Comment: Sorry for not sharing url of the page, because it is private link